# To use Object in JSP and Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, object, servlets, request

I pass an object Extract of the Servlet to JSP by `request.getAttribute`.
In my JSP I need the value that comes with an object is equal to Extract attributes. 
When I create an `Object object = new Object;` the program report the `error: Object required. Found: java.lang.Object` 
What do I do? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure about what's wrong with your code but one of the things I see is the `Object object = new Object();` You forgot the opening and closing parenthesis for the constructor `()`. And also when passing an object, you should use `request.setAttribute()` not `get()`

Comment: No. I'm using with () and I need to use get() cos I'm getting the parameter

Comment: @user3524338 Yes, from your JSP you should use `getAttribute()` to get the Object, but to pass it from your Servlet to JSP, you should use `setAttribute()`. Anyways, is it working now?